# How to run a command in the background with 'doas'?

Tags: alpine-linux, doas

I want to run a command in the background as root. And I have a problem with **doas** command.

With **sudo**, I can use `sudo --background <command>`. It will ask for password, then runs in the background. I cannot do `doas <command> &` because it will ask for the password in the background and stuck there forever.

I've checked the manpage but did not find the equivalent option for **doas**.

Comment: Does `doas` have the equivalent of `sudo -v` (basically just prompt for authentication to cache credentials for a while)? Then you could authenticate once, then run `doas <command> &` and it would use the cached credentials. If it doesn't, you can still try something like `doas true; doas <command> &`

Comment: @muru It is a nice trick.

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this would be to start an in-line script with either `sh -c` or `bash -c` (or whatever shell your command needs) using `doas`, and let that script run the command in the background. To run multiple sequential commands in the background, collect them in a subshell:

```bash
doas sh -c '(sleep 10; echo done) &'
```

The above command would start a child shell running as root, with a backgrounded subshell that waits 10 seconds before printing the string `done`.  The control of the initial non-root interactive shell would be handed back to the user as soon as the command in the in-line script has started in the background.

This would also work with `sudo`.

Comment: I've noticed that `jobs` command shows the command running in the background if I use `sudo --background`, but not when using `doas sh -c`. Maybe because `sudo --background` does not spawn a subshell? Is there anything I can do to control the status of the subshell process spawned by `doas sh -c`?

Comment: Keeping track of the subshell pid is a pain to deal with compared to a simple 'jobs' command.

Comment: @Livy Why would you need to keep track of the PID of the background process? It's not a process that belongs to your user so you can't really do anything with it. It would be simple enough to print the PID from the inline script, but your question never said anything about these requirements.